# Url.Action for area asp.net cor mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

              url = '/Masters/GLMaster/SearchGLPartial';
               // url='@Url.Action("SearchGLPartial", "GLMaster")';
               
                let name = document.getElementById("Name").value;
                let code = document.getElementById("Code").value;
             

                var data = { "Name": name, "Code": code};
                var o = Object.keys(data).map(k => k + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[k])).join("&")
               
              var resulturl=url + "?" + o;


    ...other code

</script>
```

If i changed harcoded url to below code

```
url='@Url.Action("SearchGLPartial", "GLMaster", new { area = "Masters" })';
```

My code without area is working fine.It generate url with parameter..

But for Area is not working

Current Result:( url)

```
  '/GLMaster/SearchGLPartial?area=Masters';
```

I also need to append additinal paramter ..it is conflicting

Expected output:`'Masters/GLMaster/SearchGLPartial';`

EDIT:

My End Point Routing Config:

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
            
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=LandPage}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute( name: "areas", pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
             

                                
            });
```

Comment: What about put `areas` route before `default` route?

Comment: Thank you verch @Rena now working ..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of your route template like below:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{         
     endpoints.MapControllerRoute( name: "areas", pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
     endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=LandPage}/{id?}");                               
});
```

Comment: Thanks,,..i am having issue in Ajax with modal can u pls check  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63845894/ajax-modal-popup-add-edit-in-view-with-partial-view